# f2py fails at compiling fortran subroutines

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, wrapper, f2py

I cannot get f2py to successfully compile any fortran code into a python module. I run the procedure outlined in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/getting-started.html, using the following fotran file:

```
C FILE: FIB3.F

      SUBROUTINE FIB(A,N)
C
C     CALCULATE FIRST N FIBONACCI NUMBERS
C
      INTEGER N
      REAL*8 A(N)
Cf2py intent(in) n
Cf2py intent(out) a
Cf2py depend(n) a
      DO I=1,N
         IF (I.EQ.1) THEN
         A(I) = 0.0D0
         ELSEIF (I.EQ.2) THEN
            A(I) = 1.0D0
         ELSE 
            A(I) = A(I-1) + A(I-2)
         ENDIF
      ENDDO
      END 
C END FILE FIB3.F
```

I then run the command

```
f2py -c -m fib3 fib3.f
```

which creates the .so shared library file in the same directory. In my python code I can then import fib3 as a module, however when I try to print the documentation

```
print fib3.__doc__
```

the result is 'None'. And when I try

```
fib3.fib(a)
```

I get

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fib'
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the f2py compile process, anyone have an idea?

My computer is running python 2.7, numpy 1.11, and gfortran 6.1

Comment: You should explore what is in the module then. Use `nm`, a windows dlll viewer or explore it in ipython.

Comment: I don't know if this is just a copy+paste error but I couldn't actually get `f2py` to compile your code until I indented the `subroutine` line. After this it seemed to compile fine using the provided command. Running `dir(fib3)` in `python` gives me `['__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__', 'fib']`. Could you try completely removing the generated `*.so` files and try recompiling with `f2py`, I'm wondering if there's an old version hanging around.

Comment: That was indeed a copy paste error, I corrected it above. 

When I try `dir(fib3)` I get `['__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']` but when I try `print fib3.__doc__`, I get `None`. 

I even tried removing all the `*.so` files but it still is not working. Could this be an issue with clashing versions of python and numpy or gfortran?